# Does the order of word appearance matters in keyword extraction using Textrank?

Tags: nlp, keyword

I am using textrank to extract keywords from documents. I figure the order of words appearance has some influence on the final weights of words' importance, which is not so straight-forward to understand.

Let's say we are using an undirected graph, with windows size 2, to do the keyword extraction task for sentence [w1, w2, w3, w4]. When constructing the graph, we could add edges such as (w1, w2), (w2, w1), (w2, w3), (w3, w2)...In this case, there are only two edges for word w1, but four edges for w2. Given this, without any further computation, w2 has a better chance to be a keyword than w1, and this is only due to the order of appearance. To me it does not make much sense. Is there some method that this factor could be avoided?

Comment: Instead of looking in a window of 2 you could look in the same sentence.

Comment: Also, you could ignore full stops. Instead of the text "w1 w2. w3 w4" turning into (w1,w2) (w2 w1) (w3, w4) (w4, w3) you could ignore the full stop and also include (w2, w3) (w3 w2). This way only the very first and last words in the entire text have only two connections. Even then you could say those works have a link as if the text wraps around.